# CUDA thread allocation

Tags: matrix, cuda

I am trying to implement a iterative linear solver named `"Conjugate Gradient Solver"` in `CUDA` which solves equation of form,

```
A*x=b,
```

where A is sparse symmetric positive definite matrix of size nXn,
x is unknown vector of size n with initial guess as 0 and
b is a vector of size n on right hand side of the equation.

There are many operations included in my code like Sparse Matrix-vector multiplication,vector-vector operations.

My code works fine with matrix size upto 31 X 31,but not more than 31 X 31. It may be because of the number of threads allocated to a kernel function. I am allocating threads as

```
mul<<<1,nrows>>>()
```

Here mul is a function used to perform Sparse matrix-vector multiplication and nrows is the number of rows in a sparse matrix,A.

Is this problem related to 1 wrap size=32 threads ?

If anyone knows,please suggest me.

Thank you..!!

Comment: Without any code this question is impossible to answer without speculation. Please include a [mcve].

Answer (score -2):

Try to run the **"devicequery"** program from the NVIDIA CUDA Samples to get warp size present in your installation. If its shows warp size=32 then your problem may be related to it else specific code snippet is mandatory to give any solution.